# element.replaceWith(otherEl) makes directives loose functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

At a specific event, in the link function, I change the view html, like this:

```
var html = $templateCache.get('otherTemplate')[1];
var dom = angular.element(html);
element.replaceWith(dom);
$compile(dom)(scope);
```

But some stuff breaks. Example: the ngShow, ngIf directives are not working anymore.

Does this mean that I need to somehow rebind those directives to the new view?

This is how the innitial view looks like:

```
<div 
  some-directive-that-provides-view-data>
  <h1>{{viewData.currPane}}</h1>
  <div
    ng-repeat="item in items"
    ng-if="viewData.currPane == item.name"
    the-problematic-directive="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you replace one element lower? The code's breaking because you're removing the previously bound element

Comment: That's how i have it now, and it works. But i don't want extra html if possible.

Comment: What's wrong with an extra element? As long as your overall DOM Tree is clean I don't see the real problem. Especially not in a case such as this.

Comment: What if I told you that I'm using Bootstrap, and the html structure affects the styling?

Comment: @Birowsky or that you're using a directive to paint and SVG, and nodeName's are crucial...